# JWT validation failed: BAD_FORMAT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying my hands on configuring Endpoints on Cloud Functions by following the [article](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions).

Have performed the following steps:

1) Create a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project, and deployed the following Cloud Function.

```
export const TestPost = (async (request: any, response: any) => {
    response.send('Record created.');
});
```

using following command

```
gcloud functions deploy TestPost --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http --region=asia-east2
```

Function is working fine till here.

2) Deploy the ESP container to Cloud Run using following command

```
gcloud config set run/region us-central1

gcloud beta run deploy CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME \
    --image="gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime-serverless:1.30.0" \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --project=ESP_PROJECT_ID
```

ESP container is successfully deployed as well.

3) Create an OpenAPI document that describes the API, and configure the routes to the Cloud Functions.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
    title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
    description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
    version: 1.0.0
host: HOST
schemes:
- https
produces:
    - application/json
paths:
    /Test:
      get:
        summary: Do something
        operationId: Test
        x-google-backend:
            address: https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/Test
        responses:
            '200':
                description: A successful response
                schema:
                    type: string
```

4) Deploy the OpenAPI document using following command

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy swagger.yaml
```

5) Configure ESP so it can find the configuration for the Endpoints service.

```
gcloud beta run configurations update \
   --service CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME  \
   --set-env-vars ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME \
   --project ESP_PROJECT_ID

gcloud alpha functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME \
    --member "serviceAccount:ESP_PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role "roles/iam.cloudfunctions.invoker" \
    --project FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID
```

This is done successfully

6) Sending requests to the API

Works absolutely fine.

Now I wanted to Implement authentication so I made following changes to OpenAPI document

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
    title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
    description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
    version: 1.0.0
host: HOST
schemes:
- https
produces:
    - application/json
security:
    - client-App-1: [read, write]
paths:
    /Test:
      get:
        summary: Do something
        operationId: Test
        x-google-backend:
            address: https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/Test
        responses:
            '200':
                description: A successful response
                schema:
                    type: string
securityDefinitions:
    client-App-1:
        authorizationUrl: ""
        flow: "implicit"
        type: "oauth2"
        scopes:
            read: Grants read access
            write: Grants write access
        x-google-issuer: SERVICE_ACCOUNT@PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        x-google-jwks_uri: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/SERVICE_ACCOUNT@PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I created a service account using following command.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME --display-name DISPLAY_NAME
```

Granted Token Creator role to service account using following

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID --member serviceAccount:SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL --role roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

Redeploy the OpenAPI document

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy swagger.yaml
```

Now when I test the API I get following error

```
{
    "code": 16,
    "message": "JWT validation failed: BAD_FORMAT",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
            "stackEntries": [],
            "detail": "auth"
        }
    ] }
```

I am passing the access token generated via gcloud into the request using BearerToken

cmd for generating access token is `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

Can some one point out what the issue here. Thanks...

**Edit#1:** 
I am using Postman to connect to my API's

After using the following command I am getting a different error.

**Command:**

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
```

**Error:**

```
{
    "code": 16,
    "message": "JWT validation failed: Issuer not allowed",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
            "stackEntries": [],
            "detail": "auth"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the following but I am not sure what should be here `x-google-issuer & x-google-audiences`

Comment: You left out the one section that matters. The code that is causing the error. Edit your question and show how you are using the token generated by `gcloud`.

Comment: @John Hanley, I found the issue. I was generating an access token and was using that to access the api. What u need is a signed jwt token. I will try to generate one and c if that works r not.

Comment: BTW I was accessing API via Postman...

Comment: I might be wrong, I am using my memory here. I don't think you want an Access Token, I think you want an Identity Token. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/print-identity-token

Comment: @JohnHanley I tried using identity token but am getting error. Updated the post with the error.

Comment: solved it using signed JWT Token, not sure how it will work using identity token command as I cant find a way to define the structure of JWT so there's a mismatch in signed JWT & YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I manager to solve the issue.

Two things were wrong.

1) The format of the raw JWT token, it should be as following

```
{
    "iss": SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    "iat": 1560497345,
    "aud": ANYTHING_WHICH_IS_SAME_AS_IN_OPENAPI_YAML_FILE,
    "exp": 1560500945,
    "sub": SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
}
```

and then we need to generate a signed JWT token using following command

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts sign-jwt --iam-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL raw-jwt.json signed-jwt.json
```

2) The security definition in the YAML file should be like following

```
securityDefinitions:
  client-App-1:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    scopes:
      read: Grants read access
      write: Grants write access
    x-google-issuer: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL 
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
    x-google-audiences: ANYTHING_BUT_SAME_AS_IN_RAW_JWT_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 2):

For ESP,  you should use jwt-token, or identity token.  not access token.  Please check [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication) out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I ask where does it talk about identity token in the post that u have shared.

Comment: Also using identity token is not working, updated the post with the error.

Comment: solved it using signed JWT Token, not sure how it will work using identity token command as I cant find a way to define the structure of JWT so there's a mismatch in signed JWT & YAML